# Can you name a funciton click in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to learn Javascript and I was trying to make window pop-up but I tried to do it with a function. Is there a rule where you can't name a function click?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function click() {
        alert("boom!!!");
    }

</script> 

<form>
    <input type="button" value="touch me" onclick="click()" />
</form>
```

I'm wondering why it does not work because even if click is a word that already exist in javascript, I thought that the "" would tell the browser that it is the function click that I just created.

Comment: Your title says `click`, but the code says `clic` (no `k`). Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Barmar, he asked why when he use `clic` instead  of `click` works, why can't he name his function `click`.

Comment: Please put the code you're having trouble with in the question, not the code that works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing a ";"
But no, I don't think that click is a reserved word in JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clic() {
    alert("boom!!!");
}

</script> 

 <form>
<input type="button" value="touch me" onclick="clic();" />
</form>
```

Comment: See [this detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4389178/3191599). Click isn't a reserved word necessarily but it's defined in the lexical scope. `window.click()` works fine.

Comment: I didn't either until I looked it up. Otherwise, your answer is correct.

Answer (score -3):

Try this without the parenthesis

onclick="clic"

Comment: That won't do anything. The contents of `onXXX` is interpreted as a Javascript statement.