# The onmousedown Event Doesn't Seem to be Triggering

Tags: javascript, html, onmousedown

In one of my projects the `onmousedown` event didn't seem to be doing anything when it was meant to trigger a function in a separate JavaScript file.

I tried incorporating both `onmousedown` and `onClick` on a button in a small test file to see if it was just a problem in the project, and it didn't work either, leading me to believe that I must be doing something wrong...

Here is my `test.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onmousedown="click()">Click</button>
    <span id="testSpan"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `main.js` file:

```
function click() {
  document.getElementById("testSpan").innerHTML = "SUCCESS";
}
```

To explain, the HTML button is supposed to trigger the `click()` function in `main.js`, and then cause "SUCCESS" to appear through the `span` element beside the button in the webpage; which it doesn't for me.

I have tried to do the same in a pen on codepen.io where it didn't seem to work either. Even weirder is the fact that I don't have any errors showing up at all... what am I missing?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click

Comment: Thanks, due to me searching for problems related to `onmousedown` I didn't see that problem/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because you named your function `'click'`. I changed the name to `'press'` and your code works fine!

```js
function press() {
  document.getElementById("testSpan").innerHTML = "SUCCESS";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onmousedown="press()">Click</button>
    <span id="testSpan"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look at the JavaScript documentation to know these "reserved words" for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button  onmousedown="window.click()">Click</button>
    <span id="testSpan"></span>

    <script>
            function click() {
      document.getElementById("testSpan").innerHTML = "SUCCESS";
    }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```