# JavaScript function doesn't run on click

Tags: javascript, html

Although I know a lot about these languages now such as arrays and functions, I'm having a basic problem to getting this JavaScript to run, here's the code:

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="click()" />
  <script>
    function click() {
      alert("hey");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Rename your `click()`  function. You happened to choose an unfortunate name.

Comment: `click` is a JavaScript function, and redeclaring it is causing problems. Rename it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript function name cannot set as click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click)

Answer (score 1):

You're running into this problem: [javascript function name cannot set as click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click)

You can fix this by changing the function name to something else like `function myClick`

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myClick()" />
  <script>
    function myClick() {
      alert("hey");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,like the comment above. you should use a different name instead of click()

```js
 function submit() {
      alert("hey"); }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit()" />
 </body>

</html>
```