# HTML button wont run function

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, alert

I'm completely new to javascript and html and my hello world script isn't working.  I want to get a button to trigger an alert.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="click()">
        click me
    </button>   
    <script>
        function click(){
            alert("hello world");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It conflicts with default click function of element, but you do nothing for the click function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript function name cannot set as click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click)

Answer (score 4):

This one works, something like "click" name maybe shouldn't be used as function name to be called in html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="someClick()">
        click me
    </button>   
    <script>
        function someClick(){
            alert("hello world");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Try attaching an event listener instead, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("hello world");
});
```

```html
<button type="button">
    click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

its not work because the click word is reserve word of javascript
tyr this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="oneclick()">
    click me
</button>   
<script>
    function oneclick(){
        alert("hello world");
    }
</script>
```