# Having trouble with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make Cookie Clicker for a class I'm taking, and I'm tripping up right at the beginning because of document.getElementById. Here's my html (the relevant bits).

```
<div id="cookiebox">
<input onclick="click()" type="image" src="images/cookie.jpg" class="cookie" />
</div>
<div id="cookieNumber"></div>
```

Then the corresponding javascript:

```
var cookies = 0;
function click() {
     cookies = cookies + 1;
     console.log(cookies);
     var test = document.getElementById("cookieNumber").innerHTML = cookies;
}
```

So what ends up happening is that I get a type error because it doesn't find the cookieNumber div and nothing happens. I'm well aware that this is a super newbie question, but if anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: Fixed the issue with the document.getElementById. Still can't get the function to fire though from the input.

EDIT 2: Fixed everything. Thanks @j08691.

Comment: What exactly is the typeerror, they're often misread or misunderstood.

Comment: Name your function something other than `click`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click

Comment: I'm going to add that you should avoid using the `onclick` attribute in your HTML as it can easily add confusion. In your JS I would create a `querySelector` to find the `cookie` class and add the onclick from there. `const cookie = document.querySelector('.cookie'); cookie.onclick = click();` for example.

Comment: @KevinB Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: how are you including your script?

Comment: I suspect your html isn't exactly as you've presented it here. Look for things like missing quotes or mismatched quotes/tags etc.

Comment: To those that are posting answers assuming it is a timing issue.  The function is being called from an inline binding.  At the point that the user could make that happen, the DOM is rendered.  It's not a timing issue.

Comment: @Vatsal <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CookieClicker.js"></script>

Comment: @j08691 that looks promising... though... it doesn't seem to match the error occuring unless i'm misunderstanding

Comment: The EDIT doesn't make sense.  If you can't get the method to execute through the input, how were you getting the error **in** the method to happen in the first place?

Comment: Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcqdo319/)

Comment: @Mirakurun a working fiddle should be included in an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcqdo319/). It seems to be the problem with the naming of your function as [j08691](http://httpshttps://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) mentioned.

Also, you will probably have to change your function to arrow function, since it didn't work for me without it being an arrow function as the function was undefined.

Working version:

```
<div id="cookiebox">
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png" height=100 width=100 class="cookie" />
</div>
<div id="cookieNumber"></div>

var cookies = 0;
myFunction = () => {
     cookies = cookies + 1;
     console.log(cookies);
     var test = document.getElementById("cookieNumber").innerHTML = cookies;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try wrapping your JS code inside `onload = function() { //your code here... }`, and see if it works.

This makes sure that your div has actually loaded before calling `getElementById` on it

Comment: Given that the method is called from an inline binding, how would it not be loaded?