# Comparing Password in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm comparing password in javascript and someone its not working its working on my past project before
here is the HTML

```
<form>
        <label>
            <strong>Username</strong>
            <input type="text" name="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <strong>Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="" id="password">
        </label>
        <label>
            <strong>Confirm Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="" id="confirmpassword"> 
        </label>
        <button class="button" type="submit" id="button" onclick="click();">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and here is javascript

```
function click (){
    var password =  document.getElementID('password').value,
    confirmpassword =   document.getElementID('confirmpassword').value

    if (password == ""){
        alert("Field cannot be empty.");

        
    }
    else if (password != confirmpassword){
        alert("Password didnt match try again.");
        return false

    }
    else if(password == confirmpassword){
        alert("Password Match")
        
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by when it is not working? Is it always showing- "Password Match" or one of the alerts that you have?

Comment: What's the intended purpose of the function returning `false` at seemingly random places?

Comment: none of the alertbox are showing

Comment: Related question (and maybe a duplicate, although this code has some other bugs): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click

Answer (score 2):

You are using `getElementID` to get password field value, but there is no document.getElementID function.

It should be `document.getElementById` to get that field value.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding onSubmit to the form tag and call the function there instead of in the submit button
Example:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return click();">
```

And remove the onClick from submit button

And it is not `getElementID`. It is `getElementById()`

Comment: stil not working should i erase the return false

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<form id="form-id">
        <label>
            <strong>Username</strong>
            <input type="text" name="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <strong>Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="" id="password">
        </label>
        <label>
            <strong>Confirm Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="" id="confirmpassword"> 
        </label>
        <button id="your-id">submit</button>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form-id");

document.getElementById("your-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value,
    confirmpassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;

  if (password == "") {
    alert("Field cannot be empty.");
  } else if (password != confirmpassword) {
    alert("Password didnt match try again.");
    return false;
  } else if (password == confirmpassword) {
    alert("Password Match");
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your function name because 'click' not working change it to for example submit and it works fine;

```js
function submit (){
    var password =  document.getElementById('password').value,
    confirmpassword =   document.getElementById('confirmpassword').value

    if (password == ""){
        alert("Field cannot be empty.");

        
    }
    else if (password != confirmpassword){
        alert("Password didnt match try again.");
        return false

    }
    else if(password == confirmpassword){
        alert("Password Match")
        
    }
    return false
}
```

```html
        <label>
            <strong>Username</strong>
            <input type="text" name="">
        </label>
        <label>
            <strong>Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="" id="password">
        </label>
        <label>
            <strong>Confirm Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="" id="confirmpassword"> 
        </label>
        <button class="button" type="button" id="button" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much so when i encounter somthing like this i should just change the function name?

Comment: see this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click