# Changing the color of a element with a button using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of the text using the javascript function but nothing happens when I click on the button. The files are in the same folder.

```js
function click() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.color = "red";
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<p id="test">Hello world</p>
<button type="button" onclick="click()">hello</button>
```

Comment: You haven't closed button tag. Use </buton>

Comment: I made you a snippet. I closed your `</button>`

Comment: Rename the function or use addEventListener (recommended)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click - change the function name

Comment: The main issue that your script acting on the title instead of a button, you need to add the ID to the button, not the title! and then should work also if you use the latest jQuery release use this way

    $( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
      console.log( clicked );
    });

Comment: @AleksandrsKrasnovskis Erm no. The main issue is the inline use of a function that matches a JS function called click

Comment: but you calling id="test" but it's on title not on the button!

Comment: He wants to change the color of the text Hello world when he clicks the button. The code works if the function name is changed to clickMe for example

Answer (score 0):

You had the logic right, but the naming of the javascript function is the problem.
I'm not sure why, but the `click()` function is reserved for something else and won't actually call your defined function. If you simply rename your function to something like `press()` it should actually call your function and change the color of your text

Comment: See the dupes for expanations