# JavaScript function not being called on button press

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a relatively trivial problem, that has caused me to get stumped for a few hours

I am trying to get my button to call a JavaScript function that logs to console

Here is my HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>McKinsey Prep</title>

    <div>
        <button onclick="click()">Some Button</button>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The button here is calling the click() method in this JavaScript file

```
 console.log("Code has reached here")
    function click(){
     console.log("Button was clicked REEEEe")
}
```

The script.js file only has this function, **I DO NOT** want to execute code in my HTML document

When I run my index.js it prints the first print statement but the console.log in the function call does not appear on console when I click my button

**NOTE**

I am left clicking my index.html and pressing run to run my code.

What could be the issue?

Comment: You have a reference to "script.js" in your HTML, but you talk about an "index.js" file in your text. Which is it?

Comment: [don't use HTML attributes for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers), use HTML for markup, and use JS for JS: find your button in your script, and then add the event handler to use using `addEventHandler` (and load your script with `<script src="yourfile.js" async defer></script>` so that it loads without blocking the page, and runs only once the page is ready to be queried)

Comment: Your `<div>` should be in the `<body>`, not the `<head>`

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be index.html

Answer (score 2):

Click() is a reserved name, you can't use it on a function because there is a native method on JS with that name.

Change the name of your function and try again.
[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/vmo45kx6/1/)

```
<button onclick="clicked()">Some Button</button>

 function clicked(){
 console.log("Button was clicked REEEEe")}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function, `click`, is the issue. `click` is not a reserved word in JavaScript but the name does exist elsewhere in the scope where the onclick handler runs. You have 2 options:

1. Change the function name (`doClick`, for example).
2. Qualify the function name by referring to it as `window.click` in the `onclick` handler: `onclick="window.click()"`

There's a much more in-depth explanation here: [javascript function name cannot set as click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click)

Unrelated to this, but something that could confuse someone during debugging: In your example code, your `<div>` is inside the `<head>` part of the HTML page. That content should actually be in the `<body>` section below, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>McKinsey Prep</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="doClick()">Some Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than linking to a question which has the same answer, when you have enough rep, just add a comment referencing the other question. When you have even more rep, you'll be able to flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Gotcha, will do. Thanks.